# Why am I getting a Module Build Failed in my React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

If anyone can please help. I cannot figure this out. I keep getting an error:

> **Uncaught Error: Module build failed: Duplicate declaration "status"**

I have a hook called hook.js in a file that reads this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export const hook = () => {
  const [status, setStatus] = useState([
    { title: "Progress", view: 1, total: 20 },
    { title: "Pending Initial", view: 3, total: 1 },
    { title: "Pending Review", view: 3, total: 3 }
  ]);
  return { status };
};
```

then the main.js where I am calling the hook and I get that error

```
import React from "react";
import { hook } from "./hook;

const StatusTable = ({ status }) => {
  const { status } = useComponentLogic(status);

  const StatusTableHeader = ({ status }) => {
    let header = Object.keys(status[0]);
    return header.map((key, index) => {
      return <th key={index}>{key.toUpperCase()}</th>;
    });
  };


  return (
    <div>
      <table id="status">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            {StatusTableHeade()}
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};

export default StatusTable;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the descturtured props of your `StatusTable` component and the return value of the `useComponentLogic`  hook is sharing  the same variable name, `status`, and this will definitely not work as they are both declared on the same scope.

```
const StatusTable = ({ status }) => {
  const { status } = useComponentLogic(status);
...
}
```

You should use different names for both of them. One approach would be to destructure the `status` props into a different property name.

```
const StatusTable = ({ status: inputStatus }) => {
  const { status } = useComponentLogic(status);

  ...

}
```